# What's the best way to learn Windows Powershell when coming from bash?

Tags: linux, bash, powershell

Coming from Linux land, I would like to get to know powershell. I've seen there are alot of tutorials online but can somebody point me to one which suits me best. I know quite well scripting in Bash and I have experience with several programming languages. I just want to get to know the syntax of powershell and being able to script in Windows as I do in Linux.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books , they reference two books about it.

Comment: "Shopping list" questions ("Please post a list of links to things for me") are not appropriate here. There are Meta posts [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139618/172661) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158809/172661) that explain the reasons. Voting to close as "not constructive". Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't focus on just syntax. I mean that's a start, but you want to know how it interprets what you are typing in to *really* be dangerous. The good news is it's not that hard!

Experience with C# would be better suited to picking up the powershell syntax, but there are a handful of things that mimic bash as well. Seeing as how in powershell you can incorporate any .NET class at a moment's notice, knowing C# really helped me with that part, although that's more intermediate/advanced powershell and is not needed for beginner things such as using built-in cmdlets, file copy, etc.

Now for learning material, I used the first edition [of this book](http://www.amazon.com/s?ie=UTF8&field-keywords=windows%20powershell%20in%20a%20nutshell&index=blended&link_code=qs&tag=wwwcanoniccom-20), there's a second edition out now so I just pasted the link to the amazon page that has both editions for reference. That, along with the [powershell technet reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb978526.aspx) to reference cmdlet use, and the `get-help` cmdlet itself will really catapult you into powershell.

A few tens of hours and you'll get the idea. Don't try to incorporate too much previous knowledge though, or else it won't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

A really good starting point would be the [Scripting Guy Blog](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/), in the search box type in PowerShell to get a lot of good links for working with PowerShell.

Current version is 3.0 and the integrated IDE is called Windows PowerShell ISE. The Quick Reference documentation is also really useful for getting started, [link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30002).